# mongoose promise chaining not returning promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I have a method in my express application that deletes a photo from a mongoDB using mongoose findOneAndRemove(). Everything works great and inside my promise I call a helper function that updates another document in the database.
I want this helper function to return a promise when its completed its update. But right now its stopping after Category.updateMany({name:category}, { $set: { "count" : count } } ); The updateMany worked it just didn't pass the promise up the chain. How can I get my updateCategories() method to return a promise from  Category.updateMany().

```
exports.deletePhoto = (req, res, next)=>{
  Photo.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.body.id})
  .then(photo => {
    S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);
    updateCategories( photo.category ).then((result)=>{
      res.send(photo);
    });
  })
}


// helper method Updates categories with count number of photos.

function updateCategories( category ){
  return Photo.find({category:category.toLowerCase()})
  .then( results =>{
    var count = results.length;
    return Category.updateMany({name:category}, { $set: { "count" : count } } );
  })
}
```

**UPDATED NOTE:** 
I want to keep my updateCategories() method separate as I reuse it in other methods like deletePhoto() etc. According to how promises work, you can chain them. So I'm trying to chain them so my last promise from Category.updateMany() gets returned back from the updateCategories() function.

**I just want to be able to call my below updateCategories() helper method from multiple functions and have it return a promise from Category.updateMany() inside updateCategories**

```
updateCategories().then(result =>{
  // result 
)}
```

**LAST UPDATE**
I could only get this to work by having all my promises in one method. I had to dump the second method idea. Which means duplication of code but can't seem to get it to work. Just to show its nothing to do with S3 deleteS3File method.
The below code is basically what realseanp suggested.

```
exports.deletePhoto = (req, res, next)=>{
  let photo;
  Photo.findOneAndRemove({_id:req.body.id})
  .then(p => {
    photo = p;
    S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);
    return Photo.find({ category: p.category.toLowerCase() });
  })
  .then(results => {
     return Category.updateMany({ name: photo.category }, { $set: { "count": results.length } });
  }).then(() => {
     res.send(photo);
  }).catch(e => {
     console.log("ERROR COULD NOT DELETE PHOTO = ", e );
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you don't `return` anything in the `deletePhoto` function or the callback function in there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*its stopping*", while at the same time "*Everything works great*"? What is really happening? Do you maybe get an error somewhere (I notice you're not `.catch()`ing any rejections)?

Comment: No errors are happening. By stoping I mean my updateCategories() function is not returning a promise. All I want it to do is return the promise from Category.updateMany()

Comment: Are you sure? What else is it returning? If it didn't return a promise, you should get an error about not being able to invoke the `then` method on the return value.

Comment: The then part of updateCategories does not run.

Comment: Have you tried installing an error handler instead of the `then` success handler? If the promise does reject, the then part is *expected* not to run.

Comment: Yes I added a catch to the end of updateCategories() inside deletePhoto and it didn't run either. but if I add a then() to Category.updateMany() inside updateCategories() that gets run with the result of  Category.updateMany().

Comment: Example:     updateCategories( photo.category, count ).then((result)=>{
      console.log("updateCategories result = ", result );
      res.send(photo);
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log("catch from updateCategories inside deletePhoto error = ", error);
    });

Comment: OK, that sounds like you use a broken promise implementation. What's your mongoose version, do you inject a custom promise library?

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

Comment: mongoose": "^4.11.7",

Comment: Mongoose is not the problem here. You should get that out of your head by writing as a self contained example. Create a fresh project with just the two models and enough data in each and then reproduce using only the mongoose methods. You are likely loading something else not listed here that is the real issue. Also `S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo)` looks highly suspect since surely this contacts the remote service and seems highly likely to either require callback or promise resolution itself. You also actually never check the initial `.findById()` actually returns something and is not `null`

Comment: Neil Lunn, I never said mongoose was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've kind of got some promise anti patterns happening. Updating your code to the following will work

```
exports.deletePhoto = (req, res, next) => {
  let photo;
  Photo.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id })
    .then(p => {
      photo = p;
      S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);
      return Photo.find({ category: photo.category.toLowerCase() });
    })
    .then(results => {
      const count = results.length;
      return Category.updateMany({ name: category }, { $set: { "count": count } });
    }).then(() => {
      res.send(photo);
    }).catch(e => { /* do something */ });
};
```

Or if you are using a node version that supports async await you can use the following

```
exports.deletePhoto = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const photo = await Photo.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id });

    S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);

    const catResults = await Photo.find({ category: photo.category.toLowerCase() });
    const count = catResults.length;

    await Category.updateMany({ name: category }, { $set: { "count": count } });

    return res.send(photo);
  } catch (e) {
    // There was an error - do something
  }
};
```

UPDATE:

Looks like the updateMany method returns a query - not a promise. You must execute the query to get a promise:

Note the updated updateCategories function now uses `exec()`

```
exports.deletePhoto = (req, res, next) => {
  let photo;
  Photo.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body.id })
    .then(p => {
      photo = p;
      S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);
      return updateCategories(photo.category.toLowercase());
    }).then(() => {
      res.send(photo);
    }).catch(e => { /* do something */ });
};

function updateCategories(category) {
  return Photo.find({ category })
    .then(results => Category.updateMany({ name: category }, { $set: { "count": results.length } }).exec());
}
```

Comment: Again, don't forget to either `return` the promise or `.catch()` any errors inside it.

Comment: deletePhoto seems to be an express route callback function - it won't require returning anything, but yes a catch function should be added.

Comment: @Bergi added catch 

Comment: What are the odds that `S3.deleteS3File(photo.photo);` is actually an async method itself? It seems to me that is the "real standout" issue with the code in the question. The rest is just semantics. Cleaner! But still semantic.

Comment: @realseanp Thanks. Given that it looks like an express callback function, you'll likely want to call `next(err)`.

Comment: Ok I know it works using the first way but thats not what I asked. I'm using my helper function updateCategories for a reason. I wanted to extract that function as I want to use it in other functions. I just want my promise from updateCategories() to return.

Comment: Thanks @realseanp I ended up using your solution for now of one method which I originally had in my codebase but that was not the question. I wanted it to work without duplicating Photo.find and Category.updateMany for other functions.

Comment: @eman I have added an update. Looks like updateMany returns a query, not a promise. In order to get a promise you must call `exec()` see the update in the answer

Comment: Ah nice find thats why. Thank you @realseanp for sticking with this and coming up with the solution. Thank you thank you !!!